# Function failing 'silently' with perfect syntax - How should I debug?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, error-handling

**Debugging silent JS function failure**

---

I wrote a Node connection function that connects successfully, inserts data into a database, but then fails to execute my code handling any further errors.

**How should I debug in a situation like this?**

---

Here's my relevant script:

```
var connection = createConnection();

connection.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) return callback(new Error('Failed to connect'), null);
    console.log('[Post]Connection with the officeball MySQL database opened...');

    connection.query(
        'INSERT INTO `officeball`.`sales_entries` SET category = ?, `group` = ?, date = ?, price = ?, customer = ?, seller = ?, commission = ?',
    salesData),

    function (err, rows, fields) {

        if (err) console.log(err);
        connection.destroy();
        console.log('[Post]...Connection with the officeball MySQL database closed.');

    }
});
```

And here's my console output:

```
Application initializing...
Application successfully initialized!
Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/
User username1 is attempting to validate for a hit...
Connection with the Officeball MySQL database openned...
...Connection with the Officeball MySQL database closed.
User username1 validated and is ready!
[Post] Connection with the officeball MySQL database opened...
```

---

**Note:** You'll notice two connections in the log, the first of which opens and closes successfully. That's validation. The second connection, which doesn't close, is the one initiated by the above script.

Since the logs clearly show no fatal error, you can assume that everything here is defined properly. This is a problem I haven't run into until now. Usually, if a function fails, the program ends resulting in a very specific error.

Comment: That's defined outside of this snippet. Should I show more of the code? I'm trying to keep the question small. @elclanrs

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is, have tried debugin with [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector)? Try to trace the stack there and see what you find...

Comment: @elclanrs I'll do that.

Comment: Ok, I checked it with node-inspector, but got no errors. JS fiddle noticed no syntax errors, although it did complain about the anonymous functions. From what I see, logically, that second connection close log should fire...

Is there any way for me to see why that console log / connection.destroy part isn't firing? How could that happen silently?

Comment: You're defining an anonymous function and never passing it anywhere.  Do you expect that to run?  I suspect you messed up your parentheses.

Comment: As for debugging techniques - I strongly suggest installing and running `jshint`.  For the snippet you posted here, it complains: "line 17, col 5, Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression." which is the anonymous function that never gets passed anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Aaron says, remove the ")" after "salesData" and add it after "}" 8 lines down. If you're going to use a RDB with node, check  https://github.com/luciotato/waitfor or https://github.com/luciotato/LiteScript

```
var connection = createConnection();

connection.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) return callback(new Error('Failed to connect'), null);
    console.log('[Post]Connection with the officeball MySQL database opened...');

    connection.query(
        'INSERT INTO `officeball`.`sales_entries` SET category = ?, `group` = ?, date = ?, price = ?, customer = ?, seller = ?, commission = ?',
    salesData, function (err, rows, fields) {

        if (err) console.log(err);
        connection.destroy();
        console.log('[Post]...Connection with the officeball MySQL database closed.');

    });
});
```

Also read the 2nd Aaron comment:

> I strongly suggest installing and running jshint. For the snippet you posted here, it complains: "line 17, col 5, Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression." which is the anonymous function that never gets passed anywhere. – Aaron Dufour

Comment: I'd appreciate if you'd end on a note about `jshint` or something similar, as I did in the comments.  I think that's the important long-term takeaway from this question.